# Persist state when user presses button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm new to react and am making a gallery of images, with the functionality to save/bookmark certain images (pressing a bookmark next to the respective image). There is a button to "View saved images" at the top, which will show the user just saved images. Upon pressing the button again (which becomes "View All Images"), the user can see all images again.

The way I am rendering the gallery is as follows:

```
{images.map((image, index) =< {
            if (viewSaved && savedImages.index(image) > -1) {
                     return <Image data={image}/>
             }
            if (!viewSaved) {
                     return <Image data={image} />
           }
         }
}
```

The issue here is that when the user is viewing saved images, and then unsaves an image, it disappears because it gets removed from savedImages immediately. How do I persist this state so that saved images don't disappear when you unsave them, while viewing saved images?

My thought process is I need to freeze the state, and then only update that state when the viewSaved button is clicked, but I'm unsure how to go about doing this the right way.

Comment: Consider having an array of objects in state where each image is an object with an Id, url and saved boolean. Then just update the relevant object when a user saves or un saves.

Comment: So my output rendering would still only output the objects in that array with saved boolean set to true. So when the user is looking at saved images and then unsaves an image (so I set that boolean for that image to False), then react would re-render the list right? So I would have the same issue?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. Let me throw it into a codesandbox quick

Comment: Sorry it's rushed but a long those lines. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-skjnbw?file=src%2FApp.js Ideally you want to aim to render things based on their properties then you can store everything in one place and just update the properties